# Selenium Tests runs in random order

Tags: python, selenium

I hope somebody can enlighten me about an issue I am facing with selenium.

I have a website that I would like to automate some tests so I don't have to do it manually every time. For the time being all I need is to test that the login page works to get confident a bit more with this tool.

So what I did, I implemented 2 classes to achieve this purpose.

Class 1, need to open the website and check the title of the login page

Class 2, click the sign in, insert username and password and click the login button.

Goes without saying that the workflow works just fine, but I am confused because the test runs backward. So when I run my tests, selenium logs in first, than opens another browser to check the title.

I configured the tasks like this:

```
# Main test case
class LoginTestTitle(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        path = "/Users/Users/Desktop/ChromeWebDriver/chromedriver"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
        self.driver.get("<link-to-webpage>")

    def test_title(self):
        loginPage = page.MainPage(self.driver)
        # assert loginPage.is_title_matches()
        if loginPage.is_title_matches():
            print("Found Page Title")
            assert loginPage.is_title_matches()
        else:
            print("Title not found")
```

and this class to check the login functionality

```
class LoginTestButton(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        path = "/Users/User/Desktop/ChromeWebDriver/chromedriver"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
        self.driver.get("link-to-website")

    def test_outthin_button(self):
        mainPage = page.MainPage(self.driver)
        time.sleep(5)
        if mainPage.sign_in_with_outthink():
            print("Error, no Button found")
            assert mainPage.sign_in_with_outthink()
        else:
            print("OutThink button ==> OK")

        if mainPage.username_field():
            print("Error")
            assert mainPage.username_field()
        else:
            print("Username field ==> OK")

        if mainPage.password_field():
            print("Error password")
            assert mainPage.password_field()
        else:
            print("Password field ==> OK")

        if mainPage.sign_in():
            print("Error, No sign in button found")
            assert mainPage.sign_in()
        else:
            print("Logging in ==> OK")
```

I understand that selenium setUP, will run each test separately, so I am fine if it runs the tests in 2 different browsers, but I don't understand why it runs the login before the title tests if my class has been set in this order

Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: I think it ran in alphabetic order, isn't it ?

Comment: you are right. That's weird. Changing the class name to an alphabetical order it runs correctly. thank you so much. If you want to add it as a answer I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is running in alphabetic order, I would suggest you to have a structure like this :

```
  def test_01_first():
  print('1')
  def test_02_next():
  print('2')
  def test_03_last():
  print('3')
```